# How to get a robot to follow line in 90 degree?

Tags: arduino

I have created an algorithm to follow the black line. But I have a problem where it is at the crossroads robot always completes its path forward. But I want him to go to the left. I mean, he always gives priority to moving forward and  does not explore all the ways of the maze

Knowing that all roads are a corner or a straight road only

I placed the sensors 00100 sensor[0] sensor[1] sensor[2] sensor[3] sensor[4] just the middle in black line.

```
read_sensor_values();




// i use 5 sensor 0 to 4 in table sensor[];
if(sensor[2]==HIGH){ 

  if(sensor[1]==LOW && sensor[3]==LOW){     
    go_Advance();  //straight
    set_Motorspeed(M_SPEED1,M_SPEED1);
  }
  else if(sensor[1]==HIGH && sensor[3]==LOW){ 
     go_Left();  //Turn left
     set_Motorspeed(0,M_SPEED1);
  }
  else if(sensor[1]==LOW && sensor[3]==HIGH){  
    go_Right();  //Turn right
    set_Motorspeed(M_SPEED1,0);
  }

}
else {if(sensor[2]==LOW){
   if(sensor[1]==HIGH && sensor[3]==LOW){ //Turn left
    go_Left();  
    set_Motorspeed(0,M_SPEED1);
  }
  else if(sensor[1]==LOW && sensor[3]==HIGH){  //Turn right
     go_Right();
     set_Motorspeed(M_SPEED1,0);
  }

}

else {
   go_Back();
   set_Motorspeed(M_SPEED1,M_SPEED1);
}
if(sensor[1]==HIGH){  
  if(sensor[0]==HIGH && sensor[2]==LOW){
    go_Left();
    set_Motorspeed(0,M_SPEED2);
  }
  else{  //Turn left
    go_Left();
    set_Motorspeed(0,M_SPEED1);
  }
}



if(sensor[3]==HIGH){  
  if(sensor[2]==LOW && sensor[4]==HIGH){ 
    go_Right();
    set_Motorspeed(M_SPEED2,0);
  }
  else{
    go_Right();
    set_Motorspeed(M_SPEED2,0); 
  }
}
}
}
```

Comment: How you placed sensors? `sensor[0~3]`, also put your correct full code.

Comment: 00100 sensor[0] sensor[1]  sensor[2]  sensor[3]  sensor[4] just the middle in black line

Answer (score 1):

1. A few of your conditions are contradicting each other. Check the state of each sensor in every condition.
2. If i'm not wrong, at a crossroad the state will be 11111 which is not dealt with anywhere explicitly.
   So currently at a crossroad the 'else' part inside 'if(sensor[1]==HIGH)' block and the 'else' part inside 'if(sensor[3]==HIGH)' block both will be getting executed. Probably that would be causing both motors to run and it moves forward. By the time the crossroad is over, it comes back to 00100 state and keeps moving forward.
3. The 1st if statement has 2 else statements which is incorrect if this is actual code. Assuming 2nd 'else' is an 'else if', the final 'else' will never get executed as 'sensor[2]==LOW' will always be true is 'sensor[2]==HIGH' if false.